# Did the animators make a mistake with Nami's glove after she stabbed Usopp at Arlong Park?

Tags: one-piece

During the Arlong Park arc, specifically episodes 33 and 34, Nami stabs her left hand to help Usopp fake his death before the fishmen. Following the incident, Nami wears a glove on her *right* hand. Then Usopp resurfaces (pun very much intended) and the crew learns that Usopp is not dead. We then see the glove on her left hand to cover the stab wound.

Did I just miswatch the episodes or did the animators screw up?

Comment: Not sure if you are the only one, but I don't see her wearing the glove on the right hand at all. What episode are you referring to?

Comment: It would make a better question if you also include a screenshot of the scenes ;)

Comment: I don't remember the exact episode, but I think that's how it was from the fake death scene to the learning it was fake by the crew.

Comment: @Ero Sennin I looked at the links and yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 5):

This incident occurs during anime episodes 33 and 34. Nami does not wear a glove on her right hand at any point.

See the stills from these episodes below.

**Scene 1: Nami "stabs" Usopp at Arlong Park**

Nami pretends to stab Usopp.

[image: Nami pretends to stab Usopp.]

**Scene 2: Nami returns to her room**

Nami has bandages on her left hand when she returns to her room.

[image: Bandages on Nami's left hand.]

**Scene 3: Nami meets Luffy's crew**

Nami has a glove on her left hand when she meets Luffy's crew.

[image: Glove on Nami's left hand.]

**Scene 4: Nami visits Nojiko**

Nami still has the glove on her left hand when she visits Nojiko.

[image: Glove on Nami's left hand when she visits Nojiko.]